# Push from Windows Service to IIS

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, iis, push

I have a device with a big red Panic button.
The goal is to have the Panic message on a security operator's screen as quick as possible.

Once the button is pushed on the device a message is sent in immediately to a Windows Server.
On the server after some processing a typed Panic message is created in a Windows Service called 'Event Workflow'.

The security operator's browser is signed up for HTTP push messages from a SignalIR Hub.
The Hub is hosted in the IIS.

The missing link I am looking for here is how to get the Panic messages pushed to the SignalIR Hub from the Windows Service.

Here is a basic architectural overview of the problem: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7221/7093312073_b4d33d9678_c.jpg

Thanks for your help,
Szili